# How can I get distinct data all because if Thana Code same then get last date Update in SQL

Tags: sql

```
id name Thana Date
------------------------
01 A     j    2021-05-27
01 A     k    2021-05-27 
01 A     l    2021-05-27
02 B     j    2021-06-29 
02 B     w    2021-06-29
02 B     x    2021-06-29
```

I want all rows except those which contain thana code `j`.

Comment: Sample data is great. but you should also specify the expected result.

Comment: Please check...

Comment: Seems quite simple: `SELECT id, name, Thana, Date FROM YourTable WHERE Thana <> 'j'` - does that give you the desired results?

Comment: But the title _also_ says "if Thana code same then get last date update"... That's why asked for the specified result.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to have all the rows execpt those where Thana = 'J' you can use a WHERE clause in your query :

```
SELECT id, Name, Thana, Date
FROM MyTable
WHERE Thana <> 'J'
```